# Dialogue System only plays the same words

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting, text, character

I'm trying to modify brackeys dialogue system using raycast in an interactableOjects Script so that I can talk with multiple characters, however, when I talk to Character A it appears Characters B text and if I go to Character B the same text shows up (which in character B's Case wouldn't be a problem haha). is there a way that I can tell my script to identify both different objects and play different script (I mean without having to create different layers or tags)

InteractableObjects Script:

```
public void PersonInteract()
{
    int layer_mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Person");

    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range, layer_mask))
    {
        Debug.Log("Speak");

        FindObjectOfType<DialogueTrigger>().TriggerDialogue();

    }   
}
```

DialogueTrigger Script(the one that is attached to the NPC's):

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue dialogue;
 
    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        Debug.Log("Talk");
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
       
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindObjectOfType` searches your entire scene for the *first* `GameObject` with a component matching the type you asked for, even if that object has nothing whatsoever to do with the object you hit with the raycast.

If you want a `DialogueTrigger` *on the object your raycast hit*, then you should ask that object for *its* `DialogueTrigger` component:

```
public void PersonInteract()
{
    int layer_mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Person");

    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range, layer_mask))
    {
        if (hit.transform.TryGetComponent(out DialogueTrigger trigger)) {
            trigger.TriggerDialogue();
        }
    }   
}
```

If your `DialogueTrigger` component sits at a different level of the hierarchy from the object that has the collider your raycast hits (ie. a child or parent object), then you might want `GetComponentInChildren` or `GetComponentInParent` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! this did the trick